# Override func Error! Method does not override any method from its superclass

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
}
```

Here I have an error. It says

> Method does not override any method from its superclass.

This comes multiple times, I can't fix it.

Do you know something about it?

Comment: Type `tou` and `supp` and use code completion respectively to get the proper syntax.

Comment: 'Type tou and supp' Can you send the edited code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is coming because your method signature is different than the actual ones. You should use the exact method signature for overriding (Either you should use auto-complete feature provided in Xcode or refer the documentation)

[Touches Began](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan):

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, 
         with event: UIEvent?)
{
}
```

In Swift 3 [supportedInterfaceOrientations](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations) is no longer a method, it's a computed property, so it's signature becomes:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask
{
}
```

Comment: Do you know something about my second line of code?